# How to use Amdahl's Law (overall speedup vs speedup)

Tags: parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl

Recall Amdahl’s law on estimating the best possible speedup. Answer the following questions.

You have a program that has 40% of its code parallelized on three processors, and just for this fraction of code, a speedup of 2.3 is achieved. What is the overall speedup?

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between speedup and overall speedup in this question. I know there must be a difference by the way this question is worded.

Comment: Here is a re-framing of the original question. There is a program, 40% of which can be parallelized. On this 40% part, compared to sequential execution, the parallel execution speeds-up by 2.3x i.e. runs 2.3x faster. If we use parallel execution then, compared to sequential execution, what is the speedup obtained for the entire program ?

Answer (score 1):

> ## **Q** : *What is the overall speedup?*

Best start not with the original and trivial Amdahl's law formula, but by reading a bit **more** [**contemporary view**, extending the original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3), where add-on overhead costs are discussed and also an aspect of atomicity-of-split-work was explained.

[image]

### Two sections,
one accelerated by a "local"-speed-up,
one overall result

Your original problem-formulation seems to by-pass there explained sorts of problems with real-world process-orchestration overheads **by simply postulating a (net-local)-speedup**, where a `<PAR>-able` Section-under-Review related implementation add-on overhead costs become "hidden", expressed but by a sort of inefficiency of having three-times more resources for code-stream execution, yet having but a 2.3 x speedup, not 3.0 x, so spending more than a theoretical 1/3 of the time on actually **also initial set-up** (an add-on overhead-time, not present in a pure-`[SERIAL]` code-execution ) **+** parallel-processing (doing The_useful_work, now on triple the capacity of the code-execution resources) **+ also** terminating and results-collection back (add-on overhead-times, not present in a pure-`[SERIAL]` code-execution) into the "main"-code.

"Hiding" these natural cost-of-going into/out-of `[PARALLEL]`-code-execution section(s) simplifies the homework, yet a proper understanding of the real-life costs is **crucial not to spend way more** (on setups and all other add-on overhead costs, that are un-avoidable in real-world) **than one would ever receive back** (from a wish-to-get many-processors-harnessed split-processing speedup)

```
|-------> time
|START:
|                                                                                        |DONE: 100% of the code
|                                                     |                                  |
|______________________________________<SEQ>______60%_|_40%__________________<PAR>-able__|
o--------------------------------------<SEQ>----------o----------------------<PAR>-able--o CPU_x runs both <SEQ> and <PAR>-able sections of code, in a pure [SERIAL] process-flow orchestration, one after another
|                                                                                        |
|                                                                                        |
```

---

```
|-------> time
|START:                                                         |
|                                                     |         |DONE: 100% of the code  :
o--------------------------------------<SEQ>----------o         |                        :
|                                                     o---------o    ..   ..   ..   ..   ..CPU_1 runs <PAR>'d code
|                                                     o---------o    ..   ..   ..   ..   ..CPU_2 runs <PAR>'d code
|                                                     o---------o    ..   ..   ..   ..   ..CPU_3 runs <PAR>'d code
|                                                     |         |
|                                                     |         |
|                                                     <_not_1/3_> just ~ 2.3x faster (not 3x) perhaps reflects real-costs (penalisations) of new, add-on, process-organisation related setup + termination overheads
|______________________________________<SEQ>______60%_|_________|~ 40% / 2.3x ~ 17.39% i.e. the <PAR>-section has gained a local ( "net"-section ) speedup of 2.3x instead of 3.0x, achievable on 3-CPU-code-execution streams
|                                                     |         |
```

Net ***overall* speedup** ( if no other process-organisation releated add-on overhead costs were accrued )
is:

```
     ( 60% + ( 40% / 1.0 ) )
  ---------------------------- ~ 1.2921 x
     ( 60% + ( 40% / 2.3 ) )
```